# WSO2/WSF PHP custom SOAP fault code

Tags: php, soap, wso2

I am trying to setup a custom SOAP fault code in wso2/wsf php framework. The instructions in relevant posts that say to use something like this:

throw new WSFault("CustomFaultCode", "CustomFaultDescription");

do not work (php timeouts and I get a website not available warning). The first thing that i did was to change it to:

static $ex; 
$ex = new WSFault("Sender", "CustomFaultDescription."); 
throw $ex;

and this works, but only if I use default SOAP fault codes (like Sender), not custom fault codes. I suppose that I have to make changes to the WSDL as well. What could you suggest?

Thanx a lot in advance!